# Contact form email field issue

Tags: php, forms, email, field, contacts

Hi i'm a bit new to php and i'm trying to create this contact form. The one issue I am having is the email field is being used as the receiver email and not scpianolessons.ie@gmail.com

Can anyone see where im going wrong?

Thanks.

```
<?php

$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Number = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../php/contactthanks.php\">";
exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$to = "$Email";
$from = "scpianolessons.ie@gmail.com​";
$subject = "Piano Lessons";
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Number: ";
$Body .= $Number;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($to, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$Email>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../php/contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: Be honest, you just copied the code from somewhere and have no clue what it's doing, right? In the line containing `mail()` the sender address is defined using `$Email` not `$from`, which is causing this to happen.

Comment: Yes I copied a form from css tricks and tried to change some of the fields. I am having an issue with it as I pointed out im new to it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference the wrong variable, change

```
$success = mail($to, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$Email>");
```

to

```
$success = mail($to, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$from>");
```

Answer (score 0):

In from you are saying $Email as well it should be:

```
$success = mail($to, $subject, $Body, "From: <$from>");
```